# jQuery resize a dialog move its border

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with the resizable jQuery dialog. When I resize the dialog, the broder changes. It initially looks like this:

[image]

This looks fine until I resize it for a couple times. Then it looks weird:

[image]

The border move higher and the content get smaller.

The major thing causing this bug is the `box-sizing: border-box;`

The code that reproduced the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/QBqff/2/

It is known as a jQuery bug, the report is here:  https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9137

After I applied the fix to change from `box-sizing: border-box;` to `box-sizing: content-box;`, the behaviour improved but not fixed. If you resize it for many times, you can still be able to see the colour ran off.

This is after fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/DFd74/

Could someone help me to get around this strange issue? Many thanks!

Comment: its always best to create a minimal script for such javascript/css issues , until you can replicate the issue its just hard to guess or hit & trial

Comment: I have updated the question with the minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: are you saying that after adding the fix it still does not work correctly , all i see is a little spacing on right and not the same behavior on the older one , or i am not getting what you are saying?

Comment: Yep, from the example, there would be increasing space appeared while you keep resizing it. On my project then it would be on the bottom like the one I show in the picture.

Comment: i am talking about this space https://imgur.com/a/wSsd95t , is this the one you are concerned about ?

Comment: Right, that is my concern now.

Answer (score 2):

I once had the same struggle, `resize` event helped me a lot. Maybe not the nicest way but its a way ;)

What you do is on every resize reset the width of the content area.

```
$(function() {
  var content = $('<div style="background-color: yellow">aaaaaa</div>');
  var dialog = $(content)
    .dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      modal: true,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      title: "MyTitle",
      position: "center",
      overflow: "auto",
      resize: function(event, ui) {
        let width = ($(".ui-dialog-content")[0].scrollWidth - 33.3) + "px";
        console.log(width);
        $(".ui-dialog-content").css("width", width);
      }
    });
  dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: This work on my end but when I tested on a different computer it didn't  work. At the end I just put the `height: auto !important` in my `.ui-dialog` class. Although the shape will still shrink but it won't move the border up.

Answer (score 0):

The content box you add is actually resized automatically when you resize the window and the `width` is assigned automatically as the `.ui-dialog` and `.ui-dialog-content`
divs will both have `width` and `height` set, so they are reset. You can see it in the code for `_size: function()` in [jquery-ui.js](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js).

But your problem is more of alignment as the yellow background div is left aligned and adding a `margin:0 auto;` to the div you are adding makes it aligned with the header keeping the spacing on the left and right equal.

```
var content = $('<div style="background-color: yellow; margin: 0 auto;">aaaaaa</div>');
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/DFd74/52/)